# Disable WYSIWYG?

Tags: redactor, wysiwyg, ckeditor5

I hate WYSIWYG.
I prefer to write my own html but can't figure out how to put that into a field for entries content.

I tried plain text but that does not work.
I tried to disable cleanup and purify html on Redactor and CKEditor but if i switch to the html view my code is not like it was before saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redactor applies all kinds of 'improvements' to your HTML on save. You might be able to prevent this behaviour by altering the [config](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor#configuration).

If you want to use a plain text field for html, your only problem is that Twig applies html_encode to outputted text. You can prevent this by using the `|raw` filter:

```
{{ entry.plainTextField |raw }}
```

Comment: raw works. I did check ExpressionEngine and there the field type is called "Textarea" and it's possible to disable the text formatting.

Comment: I found the "Simple Text" field plugin. In combination with raw it is like Textarea in EE.